# Do I need itextsharp.xml when creating setup for my application in C#

Tags: c#, itext

I use NuGet iTestSharp and I noticed that in the build folder it adds both itextsharp.xml & itextsharp.dll.
I am creating a setup file for my project.
I guess I need itextsharp.dll but do I need to add itextsharp.xml to the setup files as well

Comment: If you are using vs studio, you Can use clickone for creating a setup quickly and simply.

Comment: What program are you using toi create a setup ?

Comment: I use advanced installer and I pick the files I need manually. I saw the VS copies both dll & xml files and i wanted to know if I need both since I need to specify the files to copy